# Cannot get image and no visible interface

Tags: ios, save, image

When I use the saving code I get the error `@ interface` for `"secondViewController"` decalres the selector `getcachedirectorypath`.  I used

```
 @interface getCacheDirectoryPath : UIImagePickerController
```

In the .h file.
Below is .m file

```
-(UIImage *)getImageFromCacheWithName:(NSString *)name
{NSString *_imagePath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",[self     getCacheDirectoryPath],name];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:_imagePath])

{UIImage *_image =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_imagePath];

    return _image;

}

return nil;
```

Comment: you get the image path in NsLog ?

Comment: There must be some syntax erroor if you are getting no visible interface. Check it. and if your file exists at imagePath. And you making the right imagepath. You will surely get image. The code seems ok.

Comment: it looks like you've declared "`getCacheDirectoryPath`" as a *subclass* of "`UIImagePickerController`" and not a method.

Comment: Where are you getting this error ? Please post the code where the error displaying